# How to create correct spatial lag variables for a raster in R?

Tags: r, spatial, raster, nearest-neighbor, spdep

lag.listw creates incorrect spatial lag values when I use the function *spdep::cell2nb*. I have a raster file and want to create a new raster where each cell has the average value of its neighboring cells (spatial lag value).

The code below creates

1. a new raster from scratch and
2. calculates the neighbor matrix with *cell2nb*.
3. *nb2listw* constructs the weights that accord to each neighbor value.
4. *lag.listw* creates the vector of neighbor values
5. Finally I use this vector to create a new raster.

Code:

```
library(raster)
library(spdep)
##raster
r<-raster(nrows=7, ncols=8)

##raster values
v<-rep(0,ncell(r))
i<-sample(1:ncell(r),1)
v[i]<-1
values(r)<-v
plot(r)

##neighbor values
#neighbor list
nb<-cell2nb(nrow=nrow(r),ncol=ncol(r),type="queen")
#spatial weights matrix
nb.w<-nb2listw(nb,style="W", zero.policy=T)
#lagged values
nb.v<-lag.listw(nb.w,values(r),zero.policy=T,NAOK=T)

##new raster
nb.r<-r
values(nb.r)<-nb.v
plot(nb.r)
```

The first raster looks like: 
[image: Raster with own values]

The new raster with neighbor values is: 
[image: Raster with spatial lag values]

Comparing both images it becomes clear that this method values are misplaced and wrong.

The above code works only if the given raster/ cell-matrix has equal numbers of rows and columns. Test:

```
##raster
r<-raster(nrows=8, ncols=8)

##raster values
v<-rep(0,ncell(r))
i<-sample(1:ncell(r),1)
v[i]<-1
values(r)<-v
plot(r)

##neighbor values
#neighbor list
nb<-cell2nb(nrow=nrow(r),ncol=ncol(r),type="queen")
#spatial weights matrix
nb.w<-nb2listw(nb,style="W", zero.policy=T)
#lagged values
nb.v<-lag.listw(nb.w,values(r),zero.policy=T,NAOK=T)

##new raster
nb.r<-r
values(nb.r)<-nb.v
plot(nb.r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `focal` function from the `raster` package itself. It statistics based on the neighboring cell values and the own cell value. To exclude the own cell value from this calculation you have to 1) attribute a zero weight to it and 2) adapt the mean function to have one observation less.

```
##create base raster
r<-raster(nrows=7, ncols=8) 
extent(r)<-c(-60,60,-50,50) #avoid touching cells at the west and south edges
r[]<-0
r[4,5]<-1 #value at the upper edge
r[1,3]<-1 #value at the left edge
r[5,1]<-1 #value at the center
plot(r)
```

the weight matrix must have a zero value for the own value:

```
nb.w<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1),ncol=3)
```

To take the avereage of all neighboring cells (withoug the own cell value) you can create your own funciton:

```
mean.B.style<-function(x){sum(x,na.rm=T)/(ncell(nb.w)-1)}
# sum of all values devided by 8 (nr. of neighbors) 
# B style, in reference to the spdep::nb2listw function
```

To take into account, that edges have fewer neighbors you can adjust the weights with:

```
mean.W.style<-function(x){sum(x,na.rm=T)/(length(x[!is.na(x)])-1)}
# W style, in reference to the spdep::nb2listw function
```

With either of these functions you can now create a new raste containing the spatial lags:

```
nb.r<-focal(r,nb.w,pad=T,NAonly=F,fun=mean.B.style)
plot(nb.r)
```

[base raster plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7CN7.jpg)

[spatial lag raster plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncNr4.jpg)